# How does one create a sparse canopy?

Tags: pruning, figs

I am looking to grow a fig tree indoors and was very inspired by [these pictures](http://riazzoli.se/that-fig-tree/). Assuming that isn't somehow unhealthy for the tree, how would one get a purchased tree that comes like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Brown-Turkey-Fig-Tree-FIGBRO05G/207088489) to obtain the tall and spread out shape from the first picture? How long would it take?

Answer (score 2):

It is a typical form of figs, if you look the small sprout laterally on main trunk.  Figs tent to look for Sun, so to elongate in various directions.

Growth and direction is much random (but so on the picture, which is the nice part). So indoor it should grow so randomly. From time to time, you need to rotate the pot.

But it is not healthy for the tree. It is not they normal form, it is still looking for sun, to growth healthy.  Additionally, I think such pot could resists few year maximum, and then you need a new plant. But if you plant outside on spring such tree, you will get few figs to eat.  For survive the winter, it is really matter of location.

On the other hand, I think they are lateral shot, so their destiny was already set (and bad).

Comment: Figs should be grown outdoors, not indoors like that- the picture seen makes the plant look very ill indeed. If it where to be cultivated like that, then the gardener doing it should be blacklisted- I would never treat a plant like that voluntarily, I shouldn't think it would survive very long being treated like that.